# Как задать рандомное число элементов массива?

Tags: c++, c, массивы

```
void random(int arr[], int size) 
{ 
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    { 
        arr[i] = rand() % 40; 
        cout << setw(3) << arr[i] << ends; 
    } 
    cout << endl; 
} 

int main()  
{
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL)); 
    const int size = 8; 
    int arr[size]; 
    random(arr, size);
}
```

Генерируется массив с рандомными элементами, но их всего 8. Как задать рандомное число элементов массива?

Comment: Сделайте `int size = rand() % 100`, массив выделяйте динамически (а лучше вектор используйте).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так. Почитайте про динамическое выделение памяти.

```
int main()  
{
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    int size = rand() % 100;
    int *arr = new int[size];
    random(arr, size);
    delete [] arr;
}
```